# Diagnostics for M2.1 temporary detection issues

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd

My desktop computer has been working fine for more than one year.

Today the boot procedure, after hanging for some 30 seconds on a black screen, surprised me with:

```
"No Bootable Device — Insert Boot Disk and Press Any Key".
```

I restarted the machine after trying to switch off the power supply and unplug it from the mains for some minutes.
I went into the BIOS and I could see that the M.2 SSD (the first boot device) was "Not available" and the motherboard "component" list was showing "M.2 - Not detected".

After 30 minutes where I went through all stages of grief I: removed the M.2 SSD, looked at it for a while, inspected the BIOS again, mounted the M.2 SSD back.

I started the computer and now everything works like nothing ever happened.

That's good, of course, but I'm wondering if I just should forget about it or I should try to understand what happened.

- Is there anything I can try (some diagnostic tool/procedure) to understand if there is any component that is about to let me down?
- Any chance to guess if it is more a motherboard problem or the M.2 SSD itself?

In case it could be any useful:

- M.2 SSD drive Crucial MX500 1TB
- Motherboard MSI B450 Tomahawk Max
- CPU Ryzen 3700x
- Windows 10

Comment: i'd always consider electrical connectivity issues first. Smokers in the house? Pets? Dust/grease (bedroom/kitchen)? Removing & replacing the drive could just have scrubbed the contacts enough to work around it for now.

Comment: I see. Anyway, no smokers, one cat. And I would define the dust condition very much under control but of course I cannot exclude it could have caused the problem.